# Nuances between CF_SQL_DECIMAL and CF_SQL_NUMERIC

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, qoq

What are the nuances between `CF_SQL_DECIMAL` and `CF_SQL_NUMERIC`? It sounds like they both accept an argument called `scale` (per http://csis.pace.edu/~ctappert/cs615-02/support/Help/CFML_Language_Reference/lang_0277.htm).

1. If I were to provide an integer to either one in a query, would there be a difference?

   1. If not, which is better to use?
2. Is one faster?
3. Do they have differing methods for rounding?

I am using these in both query of queries (QoQ) as well as in MS-SQL queries.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are wondering which `cfsqltype` to use, it is determined by the data type of the target column. The link you posted is from a very old version of the documentation. Newer ones include a [matrix for most major databases](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html). In the case of SQL Server, it lists the following mappings:

- For `DECIMAL` columns use `CF_SQL_DECIMAL`
- For `NUMERIC` columns use `CF_SQL_NUMERIC`

Usage is pretty straight-forward. Just supply the `value` and desired `scale`:

```
    <cfqueryparam value="#someNumber#" scale="2" cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal"> 
    ... OR ....
    <cfqueryparam value="#someNumber#" scale="2" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">
```

Notes about scale:

- If omitted, the `scale` defaults to zero (0). Meaning all decimal places are dropped.
- When specified, `scale` must be an integer greater than zero, and obviously should not exceed the `precision` (total number of digits stored) of the target column

> **What are the nuances between CF_SQL_DECIMAL and CF_SQL_NUMERIC?**

From CF's perspective, they are essentially identical. CFQueryparam simply validates the input (numeric, within range, etcetera), and converts the `value` to a [`java.math.BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) object. Finally it sends the SQL off to the database for execution. That is the extent of CF's involvement. The rest is handled by the database. So any behavioral nuances are likely to be database/driver specific.

> **If I were to provide an integer to either one in a query, would there be a difference? Do they have differing methods for rounding?**

I do not think there is a single answer across the board. Overall, most databases have similar handling of decimal/numeric data types. However, the exact details may vary depending on your database/driver. So you need to review your database's documentation.

SQL Server's documentation says ["the `decimal` and `numeric` types are exactly equivalent to
each other](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd424925.aspx). (Though elsewhere they make the distinction of saying "functionally" equivalent). So they *should* behave the same way. My take on it is if one rounds, the other one will too, same with overflows.   For more details, see: [decimal and numeric (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx).

> - By default, SQL Server uses rounding when converting a number to a decimal or numeric value with a lower precision and scale. However, if
>     the `SET ARITHABORT` option is `ON`, SQL Server raises an error when
>     overflow occurs. Loss of only precision and scale is not sufficient to
>     raise an error.
> - Converting from `int`, `smallint`, ... to either `decimal` or `numeric` can cause overflow.

While you probably could use either cfsqltype in this case, again it is best to follow the API. Use the `cfsqltype` which maps to the data type of the target column.

> **in both query of queries (QoQ) as well as in MS-SQL queries.**

QoQ's are a totally different beast than database queries. They are also known to be a bit ... quirky at times. Your best bet is to check the documentation: [Query of Queries user guide](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e4fd-7ff0.html)

Comment: Thank you for the organized, well-thought response. I am still confused about rounding/truncation, though. You say that it depends on the database, but wouldn't that mean that CF is passing the scale to the db and letting it worry about conversion/truncation/rounding?

Comment: Yep, the database handles the actual rounding. (When it comes to queries, CF's role is little more than that of a messenger. It just packages up the SQL then hands everything off to the database. After that is all controlled by the database/driver). If you enable logging in your DSN, you can see this in action. Run a simple query like `SELECT <cfqueryparam value="150.698634561297" scale="2" cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal"> AS DecimalValue` (cont'd)

Comment: The logs will show that CF actually passes the full value to the database/driver `spy(..)>> x = 150.698634561297`. The database then executes the sql and finally returns the rounded result `150.70` back to CF

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm not a db architect, so I probably would never realized I could log it and check it out. Thanks a ton!

Comment: You are welcome :) Dsn logging combined with a [sql profiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528334/can-i-get-sql-profiler-for-sql2008-for-free) are great tools for learning about query preparation and execution.